# Formula to total values based on new customer sign up and existing susbscriptions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Anytime a new customer signs up (indicated by value 1 under 'New Customer'), they start paying $50 for the first 4 months and $60 after the 4th month.

```
            Month1  Month2  Month3  Month4  Month5  Month6  Month7  Month8  Month9  Month10 Month11     
New Customer    1      0       0       0       1       0       1       0       1       0       0        
Active  Cust's  1      1       1       1       2       2       3       3       4       4       4        

Total       $50.00  $50.00  $50.00  $50.00  $110.00 $110.00 $160.00 $160.00 $220.00 $220.00 $230.00
```

For example, in Month 6, you have one customer paying $50 and another $60, so that total should be $110.

I need help with creating a formula to calculate the values under 'Total'

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in my original post.

Here is the problem that I am trying to solve:
Lets say anytime the unique row changes to 1, the value of that trigger is 50 for the first 4 columns and changes to 60 from 5th column.
So, in the example that used above, there are 4 unique triggers - M1, M2,M3,M4
I showed the values of M1, M2, M3, M4 using the above logic.

My goal is to create a formula that can basically replicate the values in the row 'Total'

Correction: Value in row M2 are flipped under columns 'I' and 'J'

Comment: Isn't it a simple sum of M1 through M4? So, B7 = `=sum(b3:b6)`

Comment: First of all thank you for the response. In my question, I am trying to simplify a complex problem that requires VLOOKUP and yes, it is real-world problem. However, since I didn't provide the full context, I totally agree that it wouldn't seem like a VLOOKUP table problem. Btw, can I use an actual excel file to update my question?

Comment: LPChip:  I can't use SUM()  because there are 116 such rows and 50 columns and I don't want to populate the values manually.

Comment: Since I am unable to update the title, I will submit another post

Comment: You can edit your post, not start a new one. That will be just noise. Edit your question and put the details there, not in the comments.

Comment: Much clearer now!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

The clearest way to solve a problem like this is to layout the spreadsheet to reflect the logic and rules.  You have one rule for customers in their first four months and another rule for after that.  So I laid out the spreadsheet like this:

[image: screenshot]

Row 3 calculates the current number of customers who are in their first four months.  Columns B through D need a slightly different formula in this example because the example doesn't yet have four months.  So the formula in B3 is:

```
=SUM($B2:B2)
```

That anchors the starting point in column B and the range will expand as you replicate it into C and D.  Column E is the first point with four months, so the formula there is:

```
=SUM(B2:E2)
```

As you replicate that into the remaining columns, the start and end points will shift to reflect only customers in their first four months at that point.

There is no data in this example for row 4 until the 5th month, so the formula in F4 is:

```
 =SUM($B2:B2)
```

In month 5, only customers who started in month 1 are affected.  In the months after that, those customers still affect the monthly amount and you add later customers.

So that gives you the customer counts each month at the two rates.  The total is $50 for the customers in row 3 plus $60 for the customers in row 4.  So the formula in B5 is:

```
=50*B3+60*B4
```

Replicate that across the row.

Comment: You made this very simple for me.... Thank you so much. Appreciate it.